# I want to find the maximum value of each row in a 2d array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, max, row

I have already wrote this code but it does not work correctly if I entered negative values in the array. What should I do ?!!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void maxRow(int arr[][2],int row) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        int valueMax = arr[i][0];
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] > valueMax) {
                valueMax = arr[i][j];
                cout << valueMax << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int numbers[6][2] = {1,10,5,6,7,8,19,89,-2,17,-3,-7};
    maxRow(numbers, 6);
}
```

Comment: Seems like a job for a debugger.

Comment: Provide the output you're expecting and the output you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

You're cout should be outside the inner for loop. In your example the second element in each row is the larger one and hence the code might seem to work.

Comment: What about -2 and -5 .  in this row first element is a large

Answer (score 0):

Is this right ??

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void maxRow(int arr[][2],int row) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        int valueMax = arr[i][0];
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] > valueMax) {
                valueMax = arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << valueMax << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int numbers[3][2] = {{1,2}, {19, 2}, {-2, -5}};
    maxRow(numbers, 3);
}
```

Comment: Your inner loop can start from `j = 1` instead of `j = 0` since the `valueMax` is initialized using the `j = 0` value of the i'th row.

Comment: You should also look at [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) in a loop, where each iteration stores the greater of either the current maximum, or the return of `std::max_element`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>

void maxRow(int arr[][2],int row) 
{
    int curMax = INT_MIN;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
    {
        curMax = std::max(curMax, 
                          *std::max_element(&arr[i][0], &arr[i][2]));
    }
    std::cout << curMax;
}

int main() {
    int numbers[6][2] = {1,10,5,6,7,8,19,89,-2,17,-3,-7};
    maxRow(numbers, 6);
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/ArF7Uk)